# Latex Makefile does not see changes in include files

Tags: latex, makefile

I had a Makefile template to generate my latex documents, but there is an issue I don't understand...

My main latex file include other latex files located in ./includes/. The thing is whenever I make a modification in one of these files MAKE just don't see it and won't recompile.

The relevant part of the Makefile is this :

```
DOC ?= report.tex
PDF := $(DOC:.tex=.pdf)

INCLUDES ?=

IMG_DIRS ?= img

IMG_FILES := $(wildcard $(IMG_DIRS)/*.svg $(IMG_DIRS)/*.png)

IMG_EPS := $(patsubst %svg, %eps, $(patsubst %png, %eps, $(IMG_FILES)))

all: pdf

pdf: $(DOC) $(INCLUDES) $(BIBLIOS) $(STYLES) $(IMG_FILES) $(IMG_EPS) $(PDF)

%pdf: %tex
    $(TEX) '$(PWD)/$<'
    $(BIB) '$(PWD)/$(shell basename $(DOC) .tex)'
    $(TEX) '$(PWD)/$<'
    $(TEX) '$(PWD)/$<'
```

$(INCLUDES) is a dependency for the mane target so it should recompile. I have tried many configurations with the same result.

There is just something I'm missing, thanks to enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(INCLUDES)` variable expands to nothing (it is empty). It should contain a list of files included by the .pdf.

The following initializes it with all .tex files from `includes/` directory:

```
INCLUDES := $(wildcard includes/*.tex)
```

Comment: Actually it's a template, I call it with `INCLUDES := $(wildcard includes/*.tex)` then `include Makefile.latex.mk`, I checked with a `echo $(INCLUDES)` and the files are here.

Comment: Try running make with `-d` flag to see which dependencies it considers for your .pdf target.